# Program which accurately forward / rewind videos for a couple for seconds?

Tags: video, software-rec

Is there a program which puts videos in slow motion and allows us to forward or rewind a couple of seconds?

I have tried  Windows Media Player.. Sigma Player.. DivX player.. Veoh Player.. but none of it has this functionality.

Specifically, they can put videos in slow motion but there's no way to "rewind" or "forward" a couple of seconds. Just dragging the tracker will put the video at least 10-20 seconds ahead.

Comment: As usual a question I have also and it was closed. Good work powerful useless mods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/), the slow motion isn't great, but it works. and you can set the amount of jump and the keyboard shortcuts to use in milliseconds, to any amount you want.

I assign the arrow keys to short jumps, and `ctrl` arrow keys to long jumps.  Yes, trying to drag those bars just never lands where you want.  Some limitations of jumping on some programs are because of the way things are encoded/compressed, there is one intra coded ("solid") frame, then many frames that are built out of the differences from the intra frame.

It is also usefull to know that when dragging the seek bar around in MPC, if you hold the shift key the moves are made by KeyFrame. Jumping through the file by keyframe is fast, and restart from that position begins with a KeyFrame , or solid frame, so compressed playback is instantaious without the broken frames. (may not work for all codecs)

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) should be able to do this too. There is also Media Player Classic Home Theatre.

In VLC there are hotkey assignments available for Long jump, medium jump, short jump, and very short jump.  You can assign a key to any of these. | Tools | Preferances | Hotkey |

To Alter the length of time that any of the jumps work for It is simply a matter of going to "ALL" in preferances (bottom left). In there  is | Interface | Hotkey settings | , the advanced settings for the hotkey stuff.  There are reports that agressive use of very short jumps can crash the player
Again not all videos will be able to jump the distance you set, if the program can only jump that video type by KeyFrame.

Comment: To get close to the exact frame, seek to a few seconds before it, pause and press right arrow key multiple times to step frame by frame.

Comment: VLC seems to jump in gaps of 10 seconds. Are you aware if I could set this gap, to 3 seconds?

Comment: I will add it to the answer